# Creating a Huffman Code from Markov Chain

Tags: matlab, huffman-code, markov-chains, information-theory

I have the following probability transition matrix with each row corresponding to letters A, B, C, and D. I am trying to write a Huffman code for A, B, C, and D using these transition probabilities. I tried both by hand and in Matlab but I am confused whether or not you would make the code for AA, AB, AD, BB, ... etc or somehow account for all the probabilities and just find a code for A, B, C, and D. I do not think that this Matlab code gives the codes I am looking for.  Any suggestions would be great.

```
T=[0.7 0.2 0 0.1; 
   0 0.8 0 0.2; 
   0.7 0.1 0.2 0; 
   0 0 0.6 0.4]  %Probability Transition Matrix 

p1 = [.7 .2 0 0.1];
p2 = [0 0.8 0 0.2];
p3 = [0.7 0.1 0.2 0];
p4 = [0 0 0.6 0.4];

%Create a Huffman dictionary based on the symbols and their probabilities.
dict1 = huffmandict(symbols,p1);
dict2 = huffmandict(symbols,p2);
dict3 = huffmandict(symbols,p3);
dict4 = huffmandict(symbols,p4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have four codes, as you are constructing them, where the code used for the next symbol is selected by the previous symbol. (The first symbol would simply be sent as is.)

Note that only four symbols, or really two or three for each of your codes, is not much for Huffman coding to work with. In fact, there is only one possible Huffman code for each of the two or three symbol cases.